# What is the "openid" url of facebook?

Tags: facebook, openid, django-openid-auth

I made my `openid` in my site like this:

```js
    livejournal: {
        name: 'LiveJournal',
        label: 'Enter your Livejournal username.',
        url: 'http://{username}.livejournal.com/'
    },
    wordpress: {
        name: 'Wordpress',
        label: 'Enter your Wordpress.com username.',
        url: 'http://{username}.wordpress.com/'
    },
    blogger: {
        name: 'Blogger',
        label: 'Your Blogger account',
        url: 'http://{username}.blogspot.com/'
    },
```

And I want to add facebook as my openid provider, so, what is the url of facebook `openid`?

---

This [site](https://www.gigya.com/site/LogIn.aspx) allows login using facebook, if you want to try.

Comment: If you really want to use Facebook as an OpenID provider, you can try this service: http://facebook-openid.appspot.com/ It basically provides a bridge between OpenID and Connect.

Comment: Note that with WordPress, the username and 2nd level domain of the url can be different, so the approach mentioned above won't always work.

Comment: @Maxy-B - Is that a service we can trust?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unfortunately, Facebook does not provide OpenID authentication. They have a competing standard called Connect. Here are a few links you might find useful:

http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php
http://www.facebook.com/advertising/?connect
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/connect_auth/
http://nyquistrate.com/django/facebook-connect/
http://code.google.com/p/django-facebookconnect/

**Edit**:

I see you linked to Gigya, which allows Facebook login. If you click that link, you will notice that it says "Connect with Facebook" -- keyword "connect". Gigya uses Facebook's Connect standard alongside the free OpenID standard. They are not mutually exclusive, so feel free to mix them in order to give your users the best login experience.

Comment: He already answered the question from your update.  That site is using Facebook's "Connect" service, not OpenID.  Click on the Facebook logo and the screen it takes you to is clearly labeled as "Connect with Facebook".

Comment: You can use OpenAuth if you want to stay away from Facebook Connect.  This answer walks through an implementation with the DotNetAuth CTP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821747/facebook-twitter-with-dotnetopenauth/5259556#5259556

Comment: @Dau Only as a relying party, not as a provider.

Answer (score 4):

Again, as you were told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264090/how-do-i-add-facobook-openid-login-on-my-site-is-there-a-site-provide-fackbook), Facebook is not an OpenID provider.  They have limited support for associating an account with an OpenID from another provider, but that's it.