# Have facebook and windowslive openid url?

Tags: php, facebook, openid, lightopenid, windows-live

I read [stackoverflow.com/questions/1827997/is-facebook-an-openid-provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827997/is-facebook-an-openid-provider.) questions.

Also I read [stackoverflow.com/questions/2264266/what-is-the-openid-url-of-facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264266/what-is-the-openid-url-of-facebook)  question. But these questions are asked 2 years ago and don't know any changes about facebook and windowslive openid.

**index.php** for openid is here(downloaded from [here](http://qpleple.com/how-to-make-people-login-into-your-website-with-their-google-account/)  ) (I used **lightopenid**):

```
<?php
require_once 'openid.php';
$openid = new LightOpenID("yourdomain.com");

$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id  ';
$openid->required = array(
'namePerson/first',
'namePerson/last',
'contact/email',
);
$openid->returnUrl = 'http://yourdomain.com/login.php'
?>

<a href="<?php echo $openid->authUrl() ?>">Login with Google</a>
```

**$openid->identity** which i tried and gave success are here :

Google : https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id

Google profile : http://www.google.com/profiles/~YOURUSERNAME

Yahoo : https://me.yahoo.com

AOL : https://www.aol.com

WordPress : http://YOURBLOG.wordpress.com

LiveJournal : http://www.livejournal.com/openid/server.bml

**My question is** : is there any link like above about facebook and windowslive? I looked facebook site (developer.facebook.com) but it is a bit complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) and windowslive ([although they annouced it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_account#Support_for_OpenID)) still not a OpenID provider. (As of the time of this post)